# FFMPEG How to overwrite existing file without making a copy?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to add a watermark to all videos in a file:
for %i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%i" -i wm.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w/2-overlay_w/2" -codec:a copy "file%~ni.mp4"

It makes a copy of each video when it's done. How can I make it overwrite the current videos so I don't get a bunch of copies? I'd like each file to be overwritten with the new changes.

Comment: Not possible...

Answer (score 0):

As Gyan said, but...

Simply outputting the files to a different directory allows you to both retain the original file names, and quickly delete the original folder of files after processing. Example below . You could end with the delete command `del *.mp4` to delete all the original files, but like overwrite, this will not send them to the recycle bin. Any errors would be troublesome to correct. Manual deleting a single folder is quick and safer.

```
    for %%i in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i %%i -vf scale=200:150 F:\ffmpeg\folder_name\%%~ni.mp4
```